# magic number of ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java

I am testing `ConcurrentModificationException` of collections using code bellow:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("a");
    list.add("b");
    list.add("c");

    for (String s : list) {
     // if (s.equals("a")) { // ConcurrentModificationException!
        if (s.equals("b")) { // -->> Magic number, NO Exception, Why? 
     // if (s.equals("c")) { // ConcurrentModificationException!
            list.remove(s);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

I don't understand why remove "b" is OK, but others NG?

Comment: It should throw a ConcurrentModificationException. Are you sure you didn't make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: No, I am sure. I tested in JDK 7

Comment: Run it in a debug mode and observe the steps carefully, you will realize why the edge values are throwing Exception.

Comment: To further that, if you also do `list.add("d");`, you'll notice that removing `"c"` no longer throws an exception either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first thing to know is that (as stated in the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2)) the following enhanced for loop:

```
for (String s : list) {
    // Do something with s
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
for (Iterator<String> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    String s = it.next();
    // Do something with s
}
```

If you have a look at the implementation of the iterator in `AbstractList`, you will see that:

- `hasNext()` doesn't check for concurrent modification, and just check if we are at the end of the list, using its size:

  ```
  public boolean hasNext() {
          return cursor != size();
  }
  ```
- the first thing done by `next()` is to call `checkForComodification()` to see if the list was modified while we are iterating:

  ```
  public E next() {
          checkForComodification();
      try {
      E next = get(cursor);
      lastRet = cursor++;
      return next;
      } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
      checkForComodification();
      throw new NoSuchElementException();
      }
  }

  final void checkForComodification() {
      if (modCount != expectedModCount)
      throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
  }
  ```

So, when you are iterating and removing the penultimate element of your list, the next instruction will be a call to `hasNext()`, which will return `false`, because removing one element caused the size of the list to be one less, and your iteration will stop without calling `next()` and throwing an `Exception`.

By the way, all of this is just an implementation detail, you should not rely on it as it can change, and use [`it.remove()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove()) to remove an element from the list while you are iterating.

Comment: Hey Florent,
So can i say that flaw is in
public boolean hasNext() {
            return cursor != size;
        }